# R Hunspell autocorrect and stemming in pipe function for 2 columns tribble / with unnest_tokens

Tags: r, spell-checking, tibble, quanteda, hunspell

I am currently unsuccessfully trying to apply an autocorrection and a stemming using `Hunspell` to my data. The data in question is a `tribble` of sentences, each with an author, which are then to be evaluated via a more complex unnest function. This solution [How do i optimize the performance of stemming and spell check in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319594/how-do-i-optimize-the-performance-of-stemming-and-spell-check-in-r) already describes a very effective way for autocorrection and stemming.

For me, the options are either to apply autocorrect and stemming to the complete sentences and then run my evaluations via `unnest`, or to check and adjust the individual words in the `pipe` function.

The following data describes my problem:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~text, ~author,
  "We aree drivng as fast as we drove yestrday or evven fastter zysxzw", "U1",
  "Today waas a beautifull day", "U2",
  "Hopefulli we learn to write correect one day", "U2"
)
```

```
df %>%
  unnest_tokens(input = text,
                output = word) %>%
  count(Author, word, sort = TRUE)
```

However, so far I have not found a solution to perform the autocorrection and stemming before this example evaluation. I would like to use only checked and matched words for the count function, for example.

I've been stuck on this problem for a while and am infinitely grateful for any input and ideas! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple guide how you can start:

You will need this function `spellAndStem_tokens` [How do i optimize the performance of stemming and spell check in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319594/how-do-i-optimize-the-performance-of-stemming-and-spell-check-in-r)

```
spellAndStem_tokens <- function(sent, language = "en_US") {
    
    sent_t <- quanteda::tokens(sent)
    
    # extract types to only work on them
    types <- quanteda::types(sent_t)
    
    # spelling
    correct <- hunspell_check(
        words = as.character(types), 
        dict = hunspell::dictionary(language)
    )
    
    pattern <- types[!correct]
    replacement <- sapply(hunspell_suggest(pattern, dict = language), FUN = "[", 1)
    
    types <- stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(
        types,
        pattern, 
        replacement,
        vectorize_all = FALSE
    )
    
    # stemming
    types <- hunspell_stem(types, dict = dictionary(language))
    
    
    # replace original tokens
    sent_t_new <- quanteda::tokens_replace(sent_t, quanteda::types(sent_t), as.character(types))
    
    sent_t_new <- quanteda::tokens_remove(sent_t_new, pattern = "NULL", valuetype = "fixed")
    
    paste(as.character(sent_t_new), collapse = " ")
}
```

then code for **First output:**

```
#install.packages("quanteda")
#install.packages("hunspell")
library(hunspell)
library(quanteda)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

df %>%  
    unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% 
    count(word, sort= TRUE) %>% 
    print(n=30)) 

   word           n
   <chr>      <int>
 1 we             3
 2 as             2
 3 day            2
 4 a              1
 5 aree           1
 6 beautifull     1
 7 correect       1
 8 drivng         1
 9 drove          1
10 evven          1
11 fast           1
12 fastter        1
13 hopefulli      1
14 learn          1
15 one            1
16 or             1
17 to             1
18 today          1
19 waas           1
20 write          1
21 yestrday       1
22 zysxzw         1
```

then code for **Second Output:**

```
df %>%  
    unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% 
    count(word, sort= TRUE) 
    mutate(word = spellAndStem_tokens(word)) %>% 
    print(n=30)

output:
  word                                                                                                              n
   <chr>                                                                                                         <int>
 1 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     3
 2 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     2
 3 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     2
 4 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
 5 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
 6 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
 7 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
 8 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
 9 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
10 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
11 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
12 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
13 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
14 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
15 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
16 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
17 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
18 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
19 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
20 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
21 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
22 we a day a are beautiful correct drive drove even fast fast hopeful learn one or to today was write yesterday     1
>
```

Comment: Hi @TarJae! Thank you very much in advance. But I don't quite understand why complete sentences are returned? It must be only single words...?

Also, I have swapped the spellAndStem function with the count function, only the corrected words should be processed further.

Comment: Could you please help me some more here? Thank you! @tarjae !